# Get nearest driver from 2.5 millions of data using mongodb

Tags: comparative-review, go, mongodb, geospatial

I have created 2.5 millions drivers dummy data, in this case lets say the drivers are moving around in the city. The driver's document look like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58da18fb5f2caa20fffa8cf8"),
    "name" : "Barbara Clark",
    "status" : true,
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            108.12309125955089,
            -7.421944444444445
        ]
    }
}
```

In order to get the nearest driver within less than `100ms` from given latitude and longitude. I created index and marked the city using this [algorithm](https://github.com/Gujarats/GenerateLocation) using example 2 :

```
// insert dummy location from latitude and longitude.
func insertDummyMarkLocation(cityName string, city *cityModel.City) {
    // some location in Bandung
    lat := -6.8647721
    lon := 107.553501
    var locations []location.Location

    // geneerate location with distance 1 km in every point and limit lenght 50 km.
    // so it will be (50/1)^2 = 2500 district
    newLocations = location.GenerateLocation(lat, lon, 1, 50)
}
```

So from above code I have successfully marked the city and then Insert all the marked locations to a collections in this case the name is `Bandung`.
After that I created collections from all the data that inserted to mongodb. We know that mongodb has unique generated `_id` so I use that. Here is one collection's name :

```
Bandung_district_58da0f8a5f2caa20ff61c1a7
```

This collections will be generated around 2500 marked location, let's call it districts. and in every district collections was inserted 1000 drivers data.

and Let's say a user request one driver in Bandung and wanted to see if there is available driver near him. So I use this query to get the nearest location/district from the user :

```
type City struct {
    Id       bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name     string        `json:"name"`
    District int           `json:"district"`
    Location GeoJson       `json:"location"`
}

// get Near district in the city with given distance in meters
func (c *City) GetNearestDistrict(cityName string, lat, lon float64, distance int64) (City, error) {
    var err error
    var city City

    err = checkMongoConnection(mongo)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Println(err)
        return city, err
    }

    collection := mongo.DB("Driver").C(cityName)

    err = collection.Find(bson.M{
        "location": bson.M{
            "$nearSphere": bson.M{
                "$geometry": bson.M{
                    "type":        "Point",
                    "coordinates": []float64{lon, lat}, // lon,lat in order is the rule from mongodb
                },
                "$maxDistance": distance,
            },
        },
    }).One(&city)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Println(err)
        return city, err
    }

    return city, nil
}
```

After successfully get the nearest district I use that `_id` to get a driver that near that district.

I have generated a dummy location which is near to the district's collection, so that the drivers inside districts collections is near around 100-500 meters, here is the query to get available driver:

```
type DriverData struct {
    Id       bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name     string        `json:"name"`
    Status   bool          `json:"status"`
    Location GeoJson       `json:"location"`
}

// struct for storing geo location in mongodb
type GeoJson struct {
    Type        string    `json:"type"`
    Coordinates []float64 `json:"coordinates"`
}

// Get available driver from given cityName and idDistrict/marked location.
func (d *DriverData) GetAvailableDriver(city, idDistrict string) []DriverData {
    collectionKey := getFormatDistrict(city, idDistrict)

    collection := mongo.DB("Driver").C(collectionKey)

    var drivers []DriverData
    err := collection.Find(bson.M{
        "status": true,
    }).Limit(100).All(&drivers)

    if err != nil {
        logger.Println(err)
    }

    return drivers
}
```

This solution is working fine and I got the driver within less than `30ms`. All the test and everything you can read it on [REAME.md](https://github.com/Gujarats/API-Golang/blob/master/README.md).

I have open source the project for the purpose of learning. You can find it here: *[Get Nearest Drivers](https://github.com/Gujarats/API-Golang)*.

My question is: Is this a good approach? Creating collections from generated marked location and inserting 1000 drivers to each of them?

Comment: Is it too slow to directly fetch the drivers depending on coordinates? Like [`geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#dbcmd.geoNear) (since you already have a 2dsphere index)

Comment: I have tried to store the drivers coordinate in one collections lets say 50.000 drivers using 2dsphere index, and yes it is slow and, it would take around `700ms` to get one drivers.

Comment: @oliverpool you could tried to use my project as an example for that, to seed one collections to 50.000 drivers, but Note only one collection.